# Showing the html code from a query dont only the text

Tags: php, html, mysql

So i created a database where i have some columns, on of them is pagebody
But when i select the column, doesnt give me the html code 
so if in the query some informetion like

```
this is my foto `<img src="foto.jpg">`
```

is show my like a TEXT

```
<p>this is my foto&nbsp;<code>&lt;img src=&quot;foto.jpg&quot;&gt;<\\code><\\p>
```

pagebody column is type=TEXT

I figured Up,  I had to change `$body= $row["pagebody"];` to

`$body = htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['pagebody']));`
maybe someone will need to know how to show the html code from a query
TOPIC CLOSED

Comment: probably you escaped the html, so your text is actually `&lt;img ... &gt;`.

Comment: in this... like this <p>this is my foto&nbsp;<code>&lt;img src=&quot;foto.jpg&quot;&gt;<\\code><\\p> how i can fix thaT?

Comment: don't store escaped html in the db in the first place, or use http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: but i want to store that be like a cms

Comment: you should always store data in "native" format, and then encode/escape/whatever for the target environment.